# Парсинг строки по разделителю или вывод по негативному индексу?

Tags: python

Есть строка типа:

```
CellInfo:51342693,465,6290
```

нужно сделать парсинг строки и вывести что-то вроде:

```
Cell Info:
First String: 51342693
Second String: 465
Third: 6290
```

Как это сделать?

пробовал использовать print("First String" +s[10:19])

Но загвоздка в том , что значения меняются и могут быть короче и индексы уже работают некорректно.

```py
x=ser.readline(x)
if(re.findall("[0-9]",x)):
      values=x.split(':')[1].split(',')
      print('First String: %x ' % values[0])
```

Comment: А там только числа могут быть?

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "CellInfo:51342693,465,6290"

values = s.split(':')[1].split(',')

print('First string: %s' % values[0])
print('Second string: %s' % values[1])
print('Third string: %s' % values[2])
```

Comment: Спасибо. Почти работает , но выдаёт ошибку : "a number is required, not str" для %x format.
Пробовал дописать : "print('First string: %s' % int(values[0]))"
Ошибка пропала , но вывод не  корректен. Что-то вроде :
First string: 51c65"

Comment: Ошибка возникает , т.к. этот парсинг для строки , которая не вводится в программе, а приходит как вывод , т.е. str. А Ваш метод парсит цифры как int  .

Comment: @OleksandrShulha метод Александра все парсит как нужно. Добавьте в вопрос код, который у вас работает с ошибкой.

Comment: добавил код. Как я говорил, то вывод читается с последовательного порта как строка, поэтому ошибка

Comment: А почему вы упорно пишете в форматированной строке `%x`? Вам же предложили писать `%s` - строковую переменную. А `%x` - это шестнадцатиричное значение со знаком.

Comment: @strawdog, видимо потому, что у автора исходная строка лежит в переменной x, а не в s, как в моём коде :))

Answer (score 0):

```
l_digits = re.findall(r'[+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?', str)
 for i in range(0,len(l_digits)): 
     print('First String: ' + i.__str__() +l_digits[i])
     print('Second str: ' + i.__str__()  +l_digits[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Через регулярку:

```
import re

text = 'CellInfo:51342693,465,6290'

match = re.search('CellInfo:(\w+),(\w+).(\w+)', text)
if match:
    print('Cell Info:')
    print('First String:', match[1])
    print('Second String:', match[2])
    print('Third:', match[3])

# Cell Info:
# First String: 51342693
# Second String: 465
# Third: 6290
```